# How to use aws-sdk in Ionic 2 with Angular and TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, ionic2, aws-sdk

When I tried to import aws-sdk in one of the ts (TypeScript file) in my Ionic app:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

After putting this code **import AWS from 'aws-sdk';** in my Ionic 2 ts file, I got the following **types** of error after running my Ionic 2 apps:

**Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'Buffer'.**

**Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'Readable'.**

**Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'httpAgent'.**

**Typescript Error
Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Stream'.**

**Typescript Error
Module ''*'' has no exported member 'Readable'.**

But, the strange thing is I am able to go to the definition of the aws-sdk by clicking 'go to definition' in Visual Studio code editor (below are the codes in aws-sdk):

```
import {GlobalConfigInstance} from './lib/config';
```

`export * from './lib/core';`

`export * from './clients/all';`

`export var config: GlobalConfigInstance`

`export as namespace AWS;`

And I have checked that I have **aws-sdk** in my Ionic 2 app project, under node modules.

**NOTE**: I am **NOT** using node js in my Ionic 2 app.

So my questions are:

- Is it because I am missing something, e.g. **NOT** using NodeJS  or does anyone have any solution for me?

Thanks :)

**NOTE**: I am using Parse JavaScript SDK, AWS S3, AWS EC2, Elastic beanstalk and Ionic 2 with Angular 2.

If you think I have missed out any details, please let me know so I can add it :)

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, I recently ran into a similar error while installing the AWS JS SDK (Angular 10, Typescript, Ionic 5)

Please see my separate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610225/13714870) with a solution that fully solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
declare var AWS: any;
```

That might work.